# Fast and accurate eye and mouth detection

Tags: opencv

What is the fastest and accurate eye and mouth detection algorithm which will give performance around 1 - 5 fps on 720p photos from camera on Lumia520 or device with similar specs?
For face detection I'am using OpenCV CascadeClassifier. For eye detection I have tried [this algorithm](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5836/facial-features-detection-using-haarcascade/) which is not always gives accurate results and CascadeClassifier which is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try many algorithms, it's hard to say which one will be the best for you. Few algorithms that i am aware of:

- [Flandmark](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/) algorithm needs image and and face position on image, and returns 8 points - eyes corners, nose center, face center, and mouth corners. It's quite accurate and fast.
- Active Shape Models (ASM)/Active Appearance Model(AEM) - you can read about it for example [here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~kseshadr/ML_Paper.pdf), source code is [here](http://here) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/). Note that this solution gives you more information than Flandmark algorithm.
- Cascade classifiers - except for Haar cascades, you can use LBP(local binary patterns) and HOG(Histogram of Oriented Gradients) classifiers. Some of them are included in opencv (in `opencv\data` directory), you can try to find other or train you own as well.

Note that you can increase speed just by downscalling you images - usually it won't reduce accuracy too much.